# series convergence with cases

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

## When does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {x^n}{n^2}$ converge?

to solve this, i tried to use ratio test, and then test for multiple x cases, when $-1\lt x \lt1$, when $x=1$ and when $x=-1$

so i got:
let $a_n= \frac {x^n}{n^2}$
so:
$$L=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n}|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)^2}.\frac{n^2}{x^n}|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}|\frac {xn^2}{n^2+2n+1}|=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} |\frac{x}{1+2/n+1/n^2}|$$

$-1\lt x \lt 1$ therefore convergent from (-1,1).
$x = 1\Rightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1^n}{n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {1}{n^2}$ is a p-series, since $\alpha=2>1$ therefore convergent.

am i on the right path to solve this?
Thank you all.

Comment: You are on the right path, except you probably meant "therefore convergent $\require{cancel}\cancel{\text{from }[-1,1]}$ on (-1,1)", as in open intervals.  And since it converges at $x=1$, it must converge absolutely for $x=-1$.  So yes, you are on the right track.

Comment: yes i meant (-1, 1), thank u i will edit it

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt can  you please explain to me why "since it converges at $x=1$, it must converge absolutely for $x=−1$"

Comment: $$\left|\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|\le\sum\left|\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}\right|=\sum\frac1{n^2}$$

Comment: ahh yeah i forgot about that, thanks.